# jQuery: How to automatically recall a loop function after it ends?

Tags: jquery, function, for-loop

So here is my code:

```
function draw () {
    var length=50;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        var entity2 = $("<div class='ab' id='infinite"+i+"'></div>"); //&#8734
        entity2.html(pi[i]);
        entity2.css({'left':window.innerWidth/length*(i), 'top':pi[i]*window.innerHeight/20+window.innerHeight/2, 'position':'absolute', 'color':color[pi[i]]});
        $('body').append(entity2);
    }

    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        for (a=i; a<length; a++) {
            $('#infinite'+i).animate({'top':pi[a]*window.innerHeight/20+window.innerHeight/2+'px', 'color':color[pi[a]]});
        } 
    };
};
```

The animation stops when the loop ends. How can I make it restart again automatically after it stops?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `setInterval` method to get the things done ?

Comment: @Sushanth-- cause I want the loop ends, kind of pauses, and starts again. I will be a different diaplay. I guess setInterval does work, but I need to count the time preciously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a setTimeout

```
for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
    for (a=i; a<length; a++) {
           $('#infinite'+i).animate({'top':pi[a]*window.innerHeight/20+window.innerHeight/2+'px', 'color':color[pi[a]]});
    } 
};

setTimeout(draw(),2000);
```